# How to get all the data underneath a document based on a ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

currently i'm learning Firestore and struggling to write a query. I want to target all the fields under the giMXcFmLUxfCaCmyYo0TJFeEHBL2 document. My query is looking like this:

```
 if (userId) {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('userLists')
    .doc(userId)
    .get()
    .then(docRef => {
      console.log('DATA', docRef.data());
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Nothing here');
    });
 }
```

docRef.data() is keep saying it is undefined.. what am i doing wrong (sorry for maybe dumb question..).
My goal is to get all the objects e.g.

```
2gzrNnVjpKOGLz2lxT6n
  id: "2gzrNnVjpKOGLz2lxT6n"
  time: 31 January 2021 at 00:00:00 UTC+1
```

Security Rules:

```
    rules_version = '2';
      service cloud.firestore {
        match /databases/{database}/documents {
          match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if false;
          }
    
          match /lists/{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if true;
          }
    
          match /users/{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if true;
          }
    
          match /userLists/{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if true;
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check that `userId` has the correct value, i.e. that `console.log(userId)` prints `giMXc...`? Your code seems ok (note however that `docRef`is a `DocumentSnapshot`, not a `DocumentReference`, but that's just a detail of variable naming)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
The console says:
userId giMXcFmLUxfCaCmyYo0TJFeEhBL2
So the userId variable should be the same.

Comment: There might be a security rule that prevents reading the doc. You should use the `exists` property to check if you can read the doc, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=0#get_a_document

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I added the exists check and then the console says: No such document!

Comment: Any security rules that prevent reading the doc? Are you 100% sure you are using the correct Firebase project?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec the firebase Project is the right one.. the security rule is:

    match /userLists/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }

Comment: ```
firebase.firestore().collection('userLists').where('id', '==', userId).get().then((querySnapshot) => {});
```

In my opinion you should try something like this.

Comment: @Kundan This is giving the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could query your Firestore database (since we can see your project ID) and it appears that the exact ID of your document is " giMXcFmLUxfCaCmyYo0TJFeEhBL2" and not "giMXcFmLUxfCaCmyYo0TJFeEhBL2": the first character is a space.

What is weird (and misleading) is that the Firestore console does not show the space when displaying the doc ID in the collection (see the red rectangle in the image below, which is an example in one of my projects), but if you click on the area where the document path is displayed, you can see the space (see the blue rectangle in the image below).

[image]

I could discover that by querying the collection with:

```
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('userLists')
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
    });
```

---

(I would suggest you secure your Firestore DB since the Firebase project ID is published)