# Firestore - Phantom duplication of the collection when adding a doc to a sub-collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I use firestore in a web project. With a page I try to add document in ref "Organisation/Ligue-ujYYEFE9lAPt6DrehBDG/Company" and "Organisation/Ligue-ujYYEFE9lAPt6DrehBDG/Promise" (The sub-collection "Company" and "Promise" already have a document). After added the document, it is display as *italic* in a other collection with the same id.

The code use to set document are really standard:

```
firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("Organisation")
        .doc(organisationId)
        .collection("Company")
        .doc(companyData.companyId)
        .set(companyData)
```

Main collection :
[image: Main collection]

Italic collection created:
[image: Italic collection]

Comment: Are you 100% sure there isn't an extra space in the parent doc ID when you add the doc to the subcollection?

Comment: I'm so blazed you were right there was a space at the beginning of my collection id

Comment: Glad I could help you. I will write an answer with all the explanations on why I  thought it was a problem like that.

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your Firebase console screenshot, it is most probably because there is an extra space in front of the ID of the `Organisation` document shown in italic.

How can we make this assumption?

**FIRSTLY**, we see twice in the console the ID `Ligue-ujYYEFE9lAPt6DrehBDG`, once in italic, once in non italic.

For the ID in italic it means that this document is only present as the "container" of one or more sub-collection but that it not a "genuine" document (**it does not exist**, it is a kind of "ghost"). See more info in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55590692/3371862).

On the other hand, the ID which is not in italic corresponds to the document shown in the screenshot in your question (the one with the fields hidden by the black rectangle). **This document does exist**.

So, since we cannot have two documents with the same ID in a given collection, we can conclude that the genuine doc and the "ghost" **don't have the same ID**... even if we see it being the same in the console...

**SECONDLY**, I remembered one of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65980438/3371862) demonstrating that in case a Firestore document has an extra space at the beginning of its ID, the Firestore console does not show this extra space when displaying it in the collection.

**=> CONCLUSION:** Most probably there is an extra space in front of the ID of the `Organisation` document shown in italic.